# AsyncTask and onPreExecute

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I run the AsyncTask below, I can see the log messages. However progress bar wont change visibility.

Below, is my AsyncTask code.

```
class test extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    private Context mContext;

    public PostWav(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... params ) {
        URL url= null;
        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        InputStream inputStream;

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());


        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object.put("provider_id",1);


            String message = object.toString();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toString());

            httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(message, "UTF8"));

            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            String boundary = "-------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);

            File file = getDir("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

            File wavFile = new File(file.getPath() + "/" + params[3]);

            ContentType contentType = ContentType.create("audio/x-wav");
            FileBody cbFile = new FileBody(wavFile,contentType,"sample");
            builder.addPart("sample", cbFile);
            builder.setBoundary(boundary);
            httppost.setEntity(builder.build());
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            Header[] header =   response.getHeaders("Location");
            String location = String.valueOf(header[0].getValue());
            inputStream = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            return location;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("Async-Example", "onPreExecute Called");
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        record.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {
        Log.i("Async-Example", "onPostExecute Called");

        loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        record.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}
```

I am uploading a .wav file to a my API. I did not included whole code this is basically all that I'm doing.

Comment: what does won't change means? does it doesn't appear or it doesn't disaapear

Comment: sorry for the poor context.
loading is a progress_bar.

Comment: wont change means that the progress_bar never appears

Comment: Show the whole snippet of your asynctask

Comment: How are you passing the progress bar to AsyncTask?

Comment: try to change the visibility before calling super... might change something

Comment: Are you sure the progress_bar is positioned correctly in the layout file? You might want to try to temporarily default the progress_bar to visible to make sure it displays and isn't hidden behind another element before trying to get toggling of its visibility to work in the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: it can be, i will run some tests

Comment: How are you creating and executing your task? Please show the code. You are not using .get() is it?

Comment: iam using .get() yes ... 
I need to wait for the result and set it equal to a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@greenapps Thanks mate your hint was more than enough for me to understand the problem.

Basically when I imported this class from another project I completely forgot the reason she was programmed like that.
I just had to remove .get() from the execute command and passed the methods to the post execute on the Task and everything when smoothly.

I am sorry for taking everyone's time, I really appreciated the help!

Here is the result i was looking for:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would like to show the progress bar **while** the task is being completed, so you need to work around this statement.

Try to do the work in the following method(s):

- doInBackground(int Progress)
- OnProgressUpdate() to update the progress bar according to your ideas

For more read the [following documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: This won't solve the problem, because he is most likely accessing UI Elements on a non UI Thread.

Comment: iam creating this async class inside the Activity, can i just edit the original post with the whole class or his that wrong?

Comment: @FabioLaranjeira Go ahead and do it by all means, but only the asynctask

Comment: activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
   // Touch UI
    }
});

Comment: done. I really don't understand. If the  "onPreExecute Called"  shows when it should why are the items not reacting accordingly ? o.0

Answer (score 0):

Normally AsyncTask runs on the UI Thread, but I have the strong assumption that you are calling this from somewhere else than the UI Thread since you are passing the Context as a Parameter.
So you can use that.

```
@Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {
         Log.i("Async-Example", "onPostExecute Called");
         activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
              loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              record.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         });


    }
```

Also remove `super.onPreExecute();` you dont need that
You have to change your constructor parameter from `Context` to `Activity` or it will be a bit more complicated.

Comment: i tested a similar solution, but i will give it another try